# How to set the value of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER in a C program so as to not sent the HTTP Header in the HTTP Post request?

Tags: c, http

I am sending a post request in http but I don't want to send the HTTP header, and I came to know that by setting some value for `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` in a C program we can avoid sending the HTTP header. I want to know how I can do this.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you are trying to do, sending a POST request without "the HTTP header" (what do you actually mean by that?) sounds very fishy.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an internal default header, set the header with no value right of the colon. Ie, if "`Content-Type`" is a default header and you want it to not be sent, you would "add" the header "`Content-Type:`" to the headers that you set with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing. You want to send an HTTP request without sending any HTTP headers *at all*? That's not possible - the headers are PART of the definition of the HTTP request.

In fact, you can send a blank HTTP request with no content but w/ the correct HTTP headers and that would be a valid HTTP request. But you simply *can't* send an HTTP request that has no headers (at all) but has a body, because without them, it's not an HTTP request.

Perhaps you just need to send a TCP message.